# Python JSON Parsing fails because of \" in the text

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make Python parse JSON correctly when there is " in the text?

```
json_data = """{
  "*": {
    "picker": {
      "old": 49900,
      "description": "Meaning \"sunshine\" and \r\n- cm."
    }
  }
}"""
clean_json = json_data.replace("\r","").replace("\n","")
print(clean_json)
data_dict = json.loads(clean_json)
pprint(data_dict)
```

If I do `.replace("\"","")` then it will match all `"` in the JSON and that will not work either.

Please help!

Comment: The problem is that you’re fighting the fact that you’re embedded this JSON into a Python string literal. That probably doesn’t actually happen except for testing, does it?

Comment: Can you please give us the accurate starting value for json_data?  The `description` you posted does not result in a legal object.  The backslashes disappear when the Python parser evaluates the structure, as you've seen.  Given that illegal starting value, recovery to a legal object is non-trivial.

Comment: @deceze the JSON code is part of a HTML page, so it will come through as a string.

Comment: Yeah, but not a string *literal* in your code. See the excellent answer below…

Comment: @deceze you were right, I used bs4 to extract data and the result didn't need all this string manipulation, it converted from json to dict as is :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're embedding JSON in a Python string literal, it's applying Python's escaping rules first, when the Python code and thus the string literal get parsed.

Meaning first `\"` is interpreted at the Python level yielding a single `"`, then this single `"` is parsed as JSON and fails.

You need to either:

- escape the `\` such that it is correctly interpreted as an actual `\` character in the resulting string (just double it)
- or use *rawstrings* (just prefix the triple-quoted string by `\`), this disables most escaping, it's generally used for regular expression string literals as they use `\` a lot, but they're also suitable for JSON string literals and other embeddings

Your version:

```py
>>> loads("""{
...   "*": {
...     "picker": {
...       "old": 49900,
...       "description": "Meaning \"sunshine\" and \r\n- cm."
...     }
...   }
... }""")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 5 column 32 (char 78)
```

escaping the escapes:

```py
>>> loads("""{
...   "*": {
...     "picker": {
...       "description": "Meaning \\"sunshine\\" and \\r\\n- cm."
...     }
...   }
... }""")
{'*': {'picker': {'description': 'Meaning "sunshine" and \r\n- cm.'}}}
```

rawstring:

```
>>> loads(r"""{
...   "*": {
...     "picker": {
...       "description": "Meaning \"sunshine\" and \r\n- cm."
...     }
...   }
... }""")
{'*': {'picker': {'description': 'Meaning "sunshine" and \r\n- cm.'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add a prefix `r` before strings

```py
import json

json_data = r"""
{
    "*": {
        "picker": {
            "old": 49900,
            "description": "Meaning \"sunshine\" and \r\n- cm."
        }
    }
}
"""

clean_json = json_data.replace(r"\r","").replace(r"\n","").replace(r'\"',"")
print(clean_json)
data_dict = json.loads(clean_json)
print(data_dict)
```

the output is

```
{
    "*": {
        "picker": {
            "old": 49900,
            "description": "Meaning sunshine and - cm."
        }
    }
}

{'*': {'picker': {'old': 49900, 'description': 'Meaning sunshine and - cm.'}}}
```